# Unity Toggle VR Mode Google Cardboard

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-vr

I'm downloaded GVR Unity SDK version 1.60.0 , I try to do a toggle for user to switch the VR mode. I searching around to find the way to toggle. Saw someone has ask the same question in unity.

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1312399/how-to-disable-google-cardboard-from-script.html

**I cannot find any file / script name "GvrViewer" in GVR Unity SDK version 1.60.0. I also check with the Demo provided, option only have Reset and Recenter**

Code bellow is a example for older version.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.VR;

public class CardBoardToggle : MonoBehaviour {

int vrModeInt;

public void ToggleVRMode(){
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("Vr Mode") == 1) {
        vrModeInt = 0;
    }
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("Vr Mode") == 0) {
        vrModeInt = 1;
    }
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Vr Mode", vrModeInt);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("Vr Mode") == 1) {
        CardBoard.SDK.VRModeEnabled = true;
    }
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("Vr Mode") == 0) {
        CardBoard.SDK.VRModeEnabled = false;
    }
}
}
```

or

```
GvrViewer.Instance.VRModeEnabled
```

Comment: Hello, Did you find the replacement for GvrViewer?. I have a requirement where I have to detect if cardboard button was triggered but the older implementation uses GvrViewer. So I would like to know how to detect the same in newer Google VR SDK.